# extract localities using geocode api in google maps android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask

[image: I want to display like this]
                       I have some trouble in this.I am totally new to android and API .I have one concept which is I have one edit text and button when I enter one place it retrieve all the localities in that location and display in list view. I am new to this concept so i dint know how to implement this concept.suggest some solutions.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
EditText ad;
Button type;

final String GOOGLE_KEY = "AIzaSyDe73ubloXet5TLk91EWgynvKU"  ;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ad=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
    type=(Button)findViewById(R.id.local);
    type.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    new GetLocationTask().execute();
    // start the AsyncTask that makes the call for the venus search.

}
private class GetLocationTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    String address;
    Address[] addrs;

    public GetLocationTask() {
      /*  this.address = a;
        this.addrs = addrs;*/
    }



    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        getLocationInfo(address);
        return null;
    }

    private void getLocationInfo(String address) {

        String query = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+GOOGLE_KEY;
        Address addr = null;
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(query);

        HttpResponse response;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            response = client.execute(httpGet);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
                int b;
                while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                    stringBuilder.append((char) b);
                }
                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
                    addr = new Address(Locale.getDefault());
                    JSONArray addrComp = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                            .getJSONArray("address_components");
                    String locality = ((JSONArray)((JSONObject)addrComp.get(0)).get("types")).getString(0);
                    if (locality.compareTo("locality") == 0) {
                        locality = ((JSONObject)addrComp.get(0)).getString("long_name");
                        addr.setLocality(locality);
                    }
                    String adminArea = ((JSONArray)((JSONObject)addrComp.get(2)).get("types")).getString(0);
                    if (adminArea.compareTo("administrative_area_level_1") == 0) {
                        adminArea = ((JSONObject)addrComp.get(2)).getString("long_name");
                        addr.setAdminArea(adminArea);
                    }
                    String country = ((JSONArray)((JSONObject)addrComp.get(3)).get("types")).getString(0);
                    if (country.compareTo("country") == 0) {
                        country = ((JSONObject)addrComp.get(3)).getString("long_name");
                        addr.setCountryName(country);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Double lon = Double.valueOf(0);
                Double lat = Double.valueOf(0);

                try {

                    lon = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                            .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                            .getDouble("lng");

                    lat = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                            .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                            .getDouble("lat");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                addr.setLatitude(lat);
                addr.setLongitude(lon);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        addrs[0] = addr;

    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract localities by calling [`AutocompleteFilter.Builder`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter.Builder). To create a new AutocompleteFilter, calling setTypeFilter() to set the filter to use. `setFilter` allows you to get the result of a Place request.

Valid values are:

- TYPE_FILTER_NONE
- TYPE_FILTER_GEOCODE
- TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS
- TYPE_FILTER_ESTABLISHMENT
- TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS
- TYPE_FILTER_CITIES

The value [`TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter#TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS) will return [`TYPE_LOCALITY`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place#TYPE_LOCALITY).

```
AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
.setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS)
.build();

autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);
```

**Note**: 
`TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS` – Returns only places that match one of the following types:

- locality
- sublocality
- postal_code
- country
- administrative_area_level_1
- administrative_area_level_2

`TYPE_FILTER_CITIES` – Returns only results matching `locality` or `administrative_area_level_3`.

Comment: please understand my question i want to extract all localities in between two locations and diplay it, when i am giving any two inputs in edittext.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingRequests   i need like this in android